# When send encoded json to mysql reject

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, database

I am building some new script for add long text with whitespace to `MySQL`. I need to send array elements using encode from `JSON` to `MySQL` table. encode also working fine. My question is when I tried to insert data `MYSQL` is reject data.

```
$day_details['description']=escape_string($_POST['description']);
$data_[]=$day_details;
$mysql_desc=json_encode($data_);

$sql="INSERT INTO 'table' 'description' VALUES ('".$mysql_desc."')";
if($conn->query($sql)){

}
```

syntax error

Comment: You need to mysqli_real_escape_string() (or equivalent) the json

Comment: i using mysqli_real_escape_string from escape_string function.when I put whitespace into text that error has shown.

Comment: `$sql="INSERT INTO table_name (description) VALUES ....` read the error message carefully it tells you where the error is near

Comment: You'll likely need to escape `$mysql_desc` regardless of escaping the description (in fact that's all you should be escaping)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1. Table and column names should *not* be enclosed in single quotes, but backticks if required (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)).
2. The column name should be in parentheses.
3. Finally, you need to escape the data *after* converting to JSON. But better yet, use a prepared query, then you don't need to escape the data at all:

```
    $day_details['description']=$_POST['description'];
    $data_[]=$day_details;
    $mysql_desc=json_encode($data_);

    $sql="INSERT INTO `table` (`description`) VALUES (?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $mysql_desc);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        // do something
    }
```

Comment: i thing the case is \\r\\

Comment: @SasinduJayampathi as long as you use a prepared statement you shouldn't have issues with special characters in the JSON. Note that you **don't** need to call your `escape_string` routine at all.

Comment: let me try with that

Comment: Thanks for everyone.this is solution.